# How to use the actual value of a string observable collection in a WPF data trigger?

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, listboxitem

I have an ObservableCollection bound to a listbox in WPF, the collection contains string values that I want to use in a data trigger to determine what DataTemplate is displayed for the ListBoxItem.

Eg if a List contains "Info" and "Trades" for example, I want the ListBox to contain two items, the first based on a template called "InfoTemplate" and the second based on a template called "TradesTemplate"

The style I am applying to the ListBox is

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="ResultsTypeTemplate" >
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="Info" />
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource InfoResultTypeTemplate}"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="Trades" />
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource TradesResultTypeTemplate}"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

The problem is that I do not think I have the right Binding property for the multi data trigger condition. I have tried "Text" but that does not seem to recognise it.

When I am using an Observable collection of type "string", how do I get the value of the string itself when looking at the Item template? I have tried just `{Binding}` but that goes into an infinite loop

Updated

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource InfoResultTypeTemplate}"/>
```

to

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
```

Just as a test and it works fine. So it's setting the ContentTemplate via the trigger that then creates an infinite loop, so obviously setting the ContentTemplate here is then triggering another trigger or check.

Update 2:

Interestingly I found out that it was the actual final DataTemplates I was trying to display that were creating the StackOverflow exception. Can anyone think why the following DataTemplate would create that exception when applied to a ListBoxItem of type string?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TradesResultTypeTemplate">
    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="2" Background="{StaticResource MenuButtonBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResultProcessedBorder}">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the Binding to

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding}" Value="Info"/>
```

as it is itself string.

Also, in order to achieve this in better way, you can use ItemTemplateSelector to select the template for your items

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but when I try that and it gets to the point of selecting it, the code goes into an infinite loop and throws a StackOverFlowException. Can you think of any reason why this might happen?

Comment: but you get your items populated correctly, the templates are applied correctly.. ?

Comment: Please try this to avoid StackOverFlowException.

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource InfoResultTypeTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Trades" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource TradesResultTypeTemplate}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

Comment: What element do I apply that style to? Surely it needs a key and to be specifically applied to something on the listbox, is it ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: Updated once more with the source of the exception, any thoughts?